# Getting all values out of JSON

Tags: json, vb.net

I'm trying to figure out how to get only values out of some JSON, as efficiently as possible.

The JSON source I am using is this:

```
{
  "_links": {},
  "chatter_count": 2,
  "chatters": {
    "moderators": [
      "user1"
    ],
    "staff": [
      "user2"
    ],
    "admins": [
      "user3"
    ],
    "global_mods": [
      "user4"
    ],
    "viewers": [
      "user5"
    ]
  }
}
```

As listed, within 'chatters' there are moderators, staff, admins, global_mods, and viewers.

For each of those little sub categories (elements? fields?), I would like to get each username.

I can currently get what I am looking for using this method:

```
Dim root1 As JObject = JObject.Parse(json1)
Dim chatters1 As JToken = root1("chatters")
Dim viewers1 As JToken = chatters1("viewers")
Dim mods1 As JToken = chatters1("moderators")

    For Each person As String In mods1.Children
                 'do something with person
    Next
```

And just simply altering that For Each per category/Jtoken I declared.

Another way I just sort of stumbled upon as I was haphazardly messing with code is this:

```
Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(json1)

For Each item In jResults
    For Each item2 As JProperty In item.Value
        For Each item3 As JToken In item2.Children
            For Each item4 As String In item3
                MessageBox.Show(item4)
            Next
        Next
    Next
Next
```

I get exactly what I need, and I show it in a message box just as a test.

4 For Each loops seems rather excessive though, and I can't figure out how to make it more concise.

It doesn't particularly help that I'm not very familiar with JSON objects or terminology. I'm familiar with XML and that it has a root, nodes, elements, attributes, and so on.....and I've been trying to draw a parallel between JSON and XML just to help me understand it,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you just trying to get strings out of the values? Also you can probably use Linq to get at the data eaiser.

Comment: In C# you could do something like `JObject.Parse(json1).Select(i => i.Value).Cast<JProperty().Select(i => i.Children).Cast<JToken>().Cast<string>()` Which would yield an `IEnumerable<string>{"user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user5"}` I don't know how to translate this to vb

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

On your main form put this on the top:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
```

You can download and add this dll to your References from here:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

After that create simple class with all your objects in Json, paste this on your main form:

```
#Region " - Classes - "
Public Class JSON_result
    Public _links As String
    Public chatter_count As Integer
    Public chatters As String
    Public moderators As String
    Public staff As String
    Public admins As String
    Public global_mods As String
    Public viewers As String
End Class
#End Region
```

You can add more objects, depends on your Json.

To Get Data from your Json Link use this:

```
  Private Sub GetJsonData()
    Try
        Dim wc As WebClient = New WebClient
        Dim jsonlink As String = "http://yourJsonlink.com/data.txt"
        Dim jsondata As String
        jsondata = wc.DownloadString(jsonlink)
        TextBox1.Text = jsondata.ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
  End Sub
```

After that the final is to Load and show Data and values into textboxes:

```
    Private Sub LoadDataToTextBoxes()
    Try
        Dim obj As JSON_result
        obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JSON_result)(Me.TexTbox1.Text)

        _linksTXT = obj._links
        chatter_countTXT = obj.chatter_count
        chattersTXT = obj.chatters
        moderatorsTXT = obj.moderators
        staffTXT = obj.staff
        adminsTXT = obj.admins
        global_modsTXT = obj.global_mods
        viewersTXT = obj.viewers
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
   End Sub
```

You can make `TextBox1.Visible = False` on your main app, to hide Json
loaded data from the link.